# What is the difference between simulation design and simulation data?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, estimation, sampling, cross-validation

I read that there is a simulation design such as **GARCH(1,1)** and this is called simulation design. However, when I have a  model (for example a simple linear model) then I can simulate as many data points as I like. This is called simulation data, since there is no simulation design. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you give some context (quote, reference) where did you've seen the terms used like this?

Comment: I did not read exactly people saying like this but I read a paper they said they will using simulation such as the GARACH(1,1) and I read some paper say we simulate the data without saying what is the method so then I understand they are different as I said in my question. Do you think my understanding is wrong? Any comments please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GARCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity#GARCH) is a time-series model, linear regression is also a model. In both cases you use some statistical *model* as a basis for your simulation. You cannot conduct simulation without any model (I guess this is what you mean by *design*), since you always simulate something (even if you simulate white noise). *Simulated data* is the outcome of simulation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. I thought that we need to have our model to model our data, and we need a different model to have a simulation data. Could you please reference me any article or tutorials that can help me to understand it deeply. Thanks again.